# Multiple Iframe loading issues on one page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I have multiple Iframes on one page, on load few of them randomly load and few won't load or other way round.

Links for Iframes are proper , double checked.

Please suggest any jquery code or any way which all Iframes will load properly.

Thanx in advnc.

Comment: Can you post the markup/code you are using to load the iframes?

Comment: Are you using http or https pages??

Comment: @dvenkatsagar Im using Http pages

Comment: Even the ones in the iframes sources?

Comment: @dvenkatsagar yes both are from http

Answer (score 0):

Use below jquery function with document.ready :

```
if (window.top !== window.self) {
    document.write = "";
    window.top.location = window.self.location;
    setTimeout(function () {
        document.body.innerHTML = '';
    }, 1);
    window.self.onload = function (evt) {
        document.body.innerHTML = '';
    }; 
}
```